# Symfony 2: findAll method return null value for mongDB field

Tags: mongodb, symfony, findall

I'm using synfony 2 with mongoDB
I have the following document in my collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "577d40967e6ad1cc1b3c9869"
    },
    "type": "5520A",
    "numserie": "9375031",
    "desig": "CCCCC",
    "const": "FFFF",
    "code": "XXX/E/002",
    "calis": [
        {
            "type": "TENSION CONTINUE",
            "cali": [
                {
                    "val": "330",
                    "unit": "mV"
                }, {
                    "val": "3.3",
                    "unit": "V"
                }]
        }, 
        {
            "type": "Courant continu",
            "cali": [{
                    "val": "330",
                    "unit": "µA"
                }, {
                    "val": "3.3",
                    "unit": "mA"
                }]
        }]
}
```

in my document entity I used collection annotation for the field "calis":

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="collection")
 */
protected $calis;
```

when I execute `$list = $repository->findAll();` in my controller
**I get Null value for the field "calis"** (["calis":protected]=> NULL) which is not empty !!

Trying to understand the problem, I made a new method in the repository with the following code:

`public function getList() {
        $m = new \MongoClient();
        $db = $m->selectDB('mymngdb');
        $collection = new \MongoCollection($db, 'Mycollec');
        $cursor = $collection->find();
        foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($doc);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }`

**and I get all the fields correctly** !!